# Java applet embedded in HTML hangs the browser when sends email

Tags: java, javascript, applet, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to make a website that sends me an email when someone opens it. It's stored locally, so I can't use php. I decided to go with Java applet and after much work (Firefox has some serious issues with applets) it almost works. Applet is fully loaded, initialized, started and reacts to a html button.

I'm using Javamail 1.4.4 and what happens is that Firefox and Opera (both browsers react in the same way) hang and after about 20 seconds they work normally again but mail is not sent. This is the stack trace:

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.4
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL true
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://smtp.gmail.com/crossdomain.xml, version: null]
network: Connecting http://smtp.gmail.com/crossdomain.xml with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://smtp.gmail.com:80/ with proxy=DIRECT
java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.CrossDomainXML.check(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.CrossDomainXML.check(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.SecurityManagerHelper.checkConnectHelper(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.AWTAppletSecurityManager.checkConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:288)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:231)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1900)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at mai.Mai$1.run(Mai.java:66)
    at mai.Mai$1.run(Mai.java:42)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at mai.Mai.send(Mai.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.javascript.JSInvoke.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.javascript.JSClassLoader.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass$MethodInfo.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass$MemberBundle.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass.invoke0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$DefaultInvocationDelegate.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo.doObjectOp(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$LiveConnectWorker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.CrossDomainXML$2.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 39 more
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "smtp.gmail.com" "resolve")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.SecurityManagerHelper.checkConnectHelper(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.AWTAppletSecurityManager.checkConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:288)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:231)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1900)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at mai.Mai$1.run(Mai.java:66)
    at mai.Mai$1.run(Mai.java:42)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at mai.Mai.send(Mai.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.javascript.JSInvoke.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.javascript.JSClassLoader.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass$MethodInfo.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass$MemberBundle.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass.invoke0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.liveconnect.JavaClass.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$DefaultInvocationDelegate.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo.doObjectOp(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.main.client.LiveConnectSupport$PerAppletInfo$LiveConnectWorker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

and this is the code of my applet (I read somewhere that I should use doPrivileged() but it seems to not make a difference in the stack trace):

```
package mai;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.security.AccessController;
import java.security.PrivilegedAction;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;



public class Mai extends Applet{

    private static final String SMTP_HOST_NAME = "smtp.gmail.com";
    private static final int SMTP_HOST_PORT = 465;
    private static final String SMTP_AUTH_USER = "myMail@gmail.com";
    private static final String SMTP_AUTH_PWD = "myPassword";

    @Override
    public void init(){
        System.out.println("init");
    }

    public void send(){
        System.out.println("send");

        AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<String>() {

                @Override
                public String run() {
                     try{

                        Properties props = new Properties();

                        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");
                        props.put("mail.smtps.host", SMTP_HOST_NAME);
                        props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
                        // props.put("mail.smtps.quitwait", "false");

                        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
                        mailSession.setDebug(true);
                        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();

                        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
                        message.setSubject("Testing SMTP-SSL");
                        message.setContent("This is a test", "text/plain");

                        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                             new InternetAddress("myMaill@gmail.com"));

                        transport.connect
                          (SMTP_HOST_NAME, SMTP_HOST_PORT, SMTP_AUTH_USER, SMTP_AUTH_PWD);

                        transport.sendMessage(message,
                            message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
                        transport.close();
                    }catch(Exception e){

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }finally{
                         return "send";
                     }
                }
            });


    }
}
```

I also read that I could sign my applet but it would invoke a pop-up every time my applet loads, which is not an option as it must be a little bit hidden.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

(If You think using an applet here is too complicated, please show me a better way. From what I know JavaScript can't send email, I don't have a server so I can't use php or something like node.js and all other libraries which send information require login from the user).

Comment: An applet that sends email but *"must be a little bit hidden"*?  Sounds downright evil.  If you achieve it, let us know how, so we can raise a security bug with Oracle and get it fixed.  TIA

Comment: This site is a present. It will have a video which is supposed to bring back memories. At the and there will be me asking this person to open the door for me. But for me to know when to come and when this person is actually watching it I need the email. If this is evil then I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the club of malicious code writers (where malicious includes tracking). You are running afoul of the same-origin policy of browsers w.r.t. new network connections, meaning that the only place you can connect to without requiring signing is the host that served the original page.